# (input) attribute in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I can't seem to find out what (input) does in Angular. Here's the code sample:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="person" (input)="filterPersons($event.target.value, 'Hair Colour')">
```

I have placed a log inside the filterPersons method to see when it is executed but nothing gets outputted at all when I click/unclick the checkbox or submit the form. What functionality does (input) actually provide?

Worth noting that there are no errors and the codebase works fine and in fact there are multiple examples of this throughout the codebase so I know it's not a simple typing error but I cannot see what effect it has.

Comment: it's use when you type something in the input

Comment: @slashsharp oh I see, in this use case, it's used for a checkbox, is that incorrect?

Comment: [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event): _"The `input` event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed."_

Comment: @mdaabis Please check my code and let me know does it resolve your problem or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you want is this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox
as the input type and then you can listen for changes via the **change** event instead of **input** (There is no input on checkbox):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" placeholder="person" (change)="filterPersons($event.target.value, 'Hair Colour')">
```

As on getting triggered on the form submit, you would have to do that programmatically or store the state when the input changes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why could not able to find what `(input)` actually does. In your code

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="person" (input)="filterPersons($event.target.value, 'Hair Colour')">
```

`(input)` call filterPersons method with 2 parameters.

Please check the stackblitz link and see the `console.log` value. It changes on every single input.

[StackBlitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fail-to-render-jonjai?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

Try providing `type="text"` / `type="number"` and I'm sure you will see your method being executed. The `(input)` event fires on every key press and can be used if you want immediate validation of an input (The `(change)` event fires when you leave the control.)